# I am learning from Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Chris Bishop any good resources?

Tags: machine-learning, references, pattern-recognition

Are there any videos or other books/notes that anyone has come across that follow Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Chris Bishop? I bought this book to learn Machine Learning and am having some trouble getting through it.

Comment: Look for existing threads tagged with the [tag:references] tag.

Comment: FWIW, I think the question is as on-topic as any other reference request. I actually think it's more specific than most because this question specifically asks for materials following a textbook, rather than just machine learning in general.

Answer (score 22):

Bishop is a great book. I hope these suggestions help with your study:

- The author himself has posted some slides for Chapters [1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-slides-1.pdf), [2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-slides-2.pdf), [3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-slides-3.pdf) & [8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-slides-8.pdf), as well as [many solutions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-web-sol-2009-09-08.pdf).
- A reading group at INRIA have [posted their own slides](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/~jegou/bishopreadinggroup/) covering every chapter.
- João Pedro Neto has posted some [notes and workings in R here](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/). (Scroll down to where it says "Bishop's Pattern Recognition and ML")
- Many introductory machine learning courses use Bishop as their textbook. Googling gives a few different ones; have a look and see which topics and focus you prefer.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend these resources to you:

1. [Tom Mitchell: Carnegie Mellon University](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/lectures.shtml)
2. (Only for Supervised Learning and follows Bishop) [Pattern Recognition: Indian Institute of Science](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbMVogVj5nJSlpmy0ni_5-RgbseafOViy) (I personally like this course as I have attended it, but this course requires you to know probability theory.)

Both the courses are maths oriented, for a lighter course on machine learning would be "Machine Learning" by Udacity

Answer (score 7):

https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/STA4273_2015/

This course closely follows part of Bishop's. It has lecture videos with it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Answer (score 6):

jupyter notebooks with python implementations and scikit-learn usage at [PRML](https://github.com/amber-kshz/PRML)

Answer (score 4):

I think an often overlooked book is [*Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms* by David MacKay](https://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/book.pdf).

It follows the general framework of PRML, since the authors seem to have a similar (at least in my view) perspective. Depending on your background -- whether or not you enjoy concepts like information theory/coding/KL-divergence -- you may find this book extremely eye-opening.